# Exception caught by gesture : The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-routes

I'm a newbie to programming and Flutter.

On my app, I've built a page navigator with a int variable. Upon change in the integer value, I would like the app to route the user to the specific designated page. However, I'm getting an 'anonymous closure' error onPressed.

**Would appreciate if someone could explain why I'm getting this error and post a rectified version of this code?**

Below is the full error snippet in the debugger.

```
Reloaded 1 of 529 libraries in 885ms.
flutter: Page #1 Clicked

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The method 'call' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: call()

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      _MyHomePageState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:navigator_test/main.dart:45
#2      _InkResponseState._handleTap
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:993
#3      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:1111
#4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:183
...
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#5df0c
    debugOwner: GestureDetector
    state: possible
    won arena
    finalPosition: Offset(208.7, 509.7)
    finalLocalPosition: Offset(76.7, 19.7)
    button: 1
    sent tap down
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Below is the depiction of the Navigator

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:navigator_test/main.dart';
import 'package:navigator_test/page1.dart';

class Navigator extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavigatorState createState() => _NavigatorState();
}

class _NavigatorState extends State<Navigator> {
  int nav = 0;

  void page1() {
    setState(() {
      nav = 1;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (nav < 1) {
      return MyHomePage(page1: page1);
    } else if (nav < 2) {
      return Page1();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm importing the Function on the Main page.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function page1;
  MyHomePage({this.page1});

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Navigation Test'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            FlatButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {
                print('Page #1 Clicked');
                widget.page1();
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
              label: Text('Goto Page #1'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you're calling `MyHomePage` directly in MyApp, without passing the argument page1, so when you press 'Goto Page #1' a null function is called. To solve the problem you can instead just call Navigator in `MyApp`:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Navigator(),
    );
  }
}
```

But the main way to navigate to a new page without needing to call setState is to use the `Navigator` class of Flutter, like this **(Just remember to remove your Navigator class first, so the IDE will know that you're calling flutter's Navigator class)**:

```
onPressed: () {
  print('Page #1 Clicked');
  //push the new route, but allowing you to go back to the previous one
  Navigator.of(context).push(

    //Default page transition of android
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => Page1(),
    ),
  );
},
```

Or:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  //Default page transition of IOS
  CupertinoPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => Page1(),
  ),
);
```

For more info see the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html).

Comment: Thanks buddy, but calling the Navigator () did not work.

Also, I'm trying to reduce the number of page instances that will come up, hence in a bid to keeping only one page at a time I'm avoiding the use of Navigator class. But I hear you, maybe I should use the Navigator class and pop the screens that I'm not using.